# Stuck at showing what the circumference of d-dimensional cube is

Tags: graph-theory

So this is the exercise 2 of chapter 1 in Diestel's Graph Theory (5th ed.). Here is the description:

Let $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and $V := \{0, 1\}^d$; thus, V is the set of all 0-1 sequences of length $d$. The graph on $V$ in which two such sequences form an edge if and only if they differ in exactly one position is called the d-dimensional cube. Determine the average degree, number of edges, diameters, girth and circumference of this graph.

Below is whatever progress I have.

(Circumference) The circumference of the graph is $2^d$.

Proof: Induction on $d \geq 2$. Let $v_{i_1,\dots,i_d}, i \in \{0, 1\}$ be vertex $v$ that has the binary string $i_1,\dots,i_d$.
Case $d$ = 2: $G$ contains four nodes, $v_{0,0}, v_{0,1}, v_{1,0}, v_{1,1}$ for which the longest cycle is 4.

Suppose that he claim holds for $d = n - 1 \geq 2$.

Case $d = n \geq 2$.

(End).

What bugs me is that I think I understand the way the longest cycle can be formed, but I do not know how to argue about is mathematically. Essentially, we can think of the node $000\dots0$ and $111\dots1$ as the leftmost and rightmost vertex respectively (essentially two end vertices), and every other vertex in-between them. Then, each vertex has $d$ neighbours and there are $2^d - 2$ vertices between the two "end" vertices. Simply start from either "end" vertex, progress through the bottommost vertex to the other end and perform zigzagging back to the starting vertex. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIt4t.png) monstrosity is my best attempt at drawing my idea. The red denotes how we form the cycle.

So how do I go about and finish this proof?

Comment: Isn't the girth the length of the *smallest* cycle?

Comment: I agree with @Angina Seng. See the case $d=4$ treated here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/957015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your title deals with the girth, while the body of your question is about the circumference; I’ll point you in the right direction to finish the argument in the body of your question.

One longest cycle on the $3$-cube is $000,100,110,010,011,111,101,001$. Notice that the second half of it can be obtained by reversing the first half and changing the last bit from $0$ to $1$. If we look just at the first two bits, the first half is a longest cycle on the $2$-cube: $00,10,11,01$, and the second half reverses that. This suggests that we might be able to use the same recipe to get a cycle of length $16$ on the $4$-cube from our $8$-cycle on the $3$-cube:

$$\begin{align*}
&0000,1000,1100,0100,0110,1110,1010,0010,\\
&0011,1011,1111,0111,0101,1101,1001,0001
\end{align*}$$

This idea is the basis for the induction step in a proof by induction that the circumference of the $n$-cube is $2^n$ for $n\ge 2$: for that step you should try to show that this procedure always produces a longest cycle in the $(n+1)$-cube if you start with a longest cycle in the $n$-cube.

Comment: I see. Is there an easy way to argue about this with the tools of graph theory? Given this, what is really holding me back is that I do not know how to express myself with graph theory. Here is how I have imagined rest of the proof: By induction hypothesis $C_n = C_{n-1}1C_{n-1}^{-1}0$, where the $1$ and $0$ indicate the ending bits and length of $C_n = 2^n$. For a sequence $C_n1C_n^{-1}0$ we note that by induction hypothesis, the last vertex differs by one to the starting vertex. Thus it is a neighbour and our sequence is a cycle of length $2^n + 2^n = 2(2^n) = 2^{n+1}$.

Comment: @Qwaster: That’s definitely the right basic idea. Try something like this. Let $v_1,\ldots,v_{2^n}$ be a longest cycle on the $n$-cube, so that each $v_k$ is an $n$-bit string. For $k=1,\ldots,2^n$ let $u_k={v_k}^{\frown}0$ (where $^\frown$ is the symbol for concatenation), and for $k=2^n+1,\ldots,2^{n+1}$ let $u_k={v_{2^{n+1}+1-k}}^{\frown}1$. Then just verify that this really is a path, i.e., that exactly one bit changes at each step.